# Is it possible to have a different super(message) be displayed for a customException?

Tags: java, exception

I have a custom exception class `InvalidNameException` that is supposed to handle an error if the input string either is too short or has any special characters.

I was wondering if it is possible to have a different `super(message)` be displayed based on what condition the input name satisfies.

It should ideally look like this but since `super(message)` needs to be the first message in  a constructor, I am curious in knowing if this is something that can be done or do I need to find another way to achieve this.

The customException class looks like this

```
    class InvalidNameException extends Exception
    {
      public InvalidNameException(String name)  {     
        if(validName(name)){  
         super("Name Contains Special Characters"); 
        }
        else if(validLength(name)){
         super("Name is too long");     
        }
      }
      public boolean validName(String name){
            boolean check = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {        
                 if (!Character.isLetter(name.charAt(i))
                  && !Character.isWhitespace(name.charAt(i))) {               
                  check = false;
              }
          }
            return check;   
      }
      
      public boolean validLength(String name){
        boolean check = true;
        if(name.length()<6) {
            check = false;
        }
        return check;  
      }
    }
```

Comment: I would suggest you should define `validName` and `validLength` outside of exception class. Initializing class conditionally inside of constructor is not ideal senario.

Comment: ah I see, will fix that , thank you. Can I ask for what reasons is it not ideal ?

Comment: Each classes' roles become unclear, and you have to write another exception handling logic(ex, in case of exception is thrown, or returning null) in calling functions.

Comment: ah I see , so if I put methods in the exception class it would require me to add try and catch statements to them as well. and since I cannot call the customexception class onto itself, I'd have to create a different exception class now to handle those methods.
Am I understanding this correctly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot call super twice. To make this work, you would have to throw a new exception for each condition like this:

```
public InvalidNameException(String name) throws Exception {
    if(validName(name)){
        throw new Exception("Name Contains Special Characters");
    }
    else if(validLength(name)){
        throw new Exception("Name is too long");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see so I can pass a custom message manually to the super class via adding a string message.
Does this also mean I would not have to also invoke `super(message)` in the constructor ?

Comment: You would not have to call super in this case.

Comment: I wouldn't expect the constructor of an exception to throw a different exception routinely

Answer (score 0):

Let's go back to beginning and say(my comment wasn't clear, sorry about that), you *can* have different `super(message)` by defining methods as static.

```java
class InvalidNameException extends Exception {
    public static InvalidNameException ofName(String name) {
        if (validName(name)) {
            return new InvalidNameException("Name Contains Special Characters");
        }

        if (validLength(name)) {
            return new InvalidNameException("Name is too long");
        }

        return null;
    }

    private InvalidNameException(String message)  {
        super(message);
    }
    public static boolean validName(String name){
        ...
    }

    public static boolean validLength(String name){
        ...
    }
}
```

By doing this, however, since exception instance is generated conditionally, you have to write another validation on calling function. Its output is not clear enough that you can easily make a mistake like `NullPointerException`.

```java
public void foobarMethod(String name) throws InvalidNameException {
    InvalidNameException exception = InvalidNameException.ofName(name);
    if (exception != null) {
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

Plus, `InvalidNameException` is defining error but also validating the data. This is the point where I said roles are become unclear.

My suggestion is to define setter method inside class that holds `name`(for say, `Person`), since storing and validating have deeper connection with each other than exception definition.

```java
class InvalidNameException extends Exception {
    private final String name;

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    private InvalidNameException(String name, String message) {
        super(message);
        this.name = name;
    }

    public static InvalidNameException invalidCharacter(String name) {
        return new InvalidNameException(name, "Name Contains Special Characters");
    }

    public static InvalidNameException invalidLength(String name) {
        return new InvalidNameException(name, "Name is too long");
    }
}

class Person {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) throws InvalidNameException {
        if (validName(name)) {
            throw InvalidNameException.invalidCharacter(name);
        }

        if (validLength(name)) {
            throw InvalidNameException.invalidLength(name);
        }

        this.name = name;
    }

    public static boolean validName(String name){
        ...
    }

    public static boolean validLength(String name){
        ...
    }
}

class Foobar {
    public void insertPerosn(String name) {
        try {
            Person person  = new Person();
            person.setName(name);
        } catch (InvalidNameException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            System.out.println("Your input is: " + e.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

There's no perfect answer for this, but at least this is my opinion.